# Joomla! - How to add extra information for user registration?

Tags: joomla, registration

I'm running Joomla 2.5.1 for my website.

For the user registration, there's only Name, Username, Password, Confirm Password, Email Address, and Confirm Email Address.

I'm able to go to 'user-profile' and enable fields such as Address, Country, etc..
However, i want to add additional information such as Company Name, etc..

May i know how can this be done?

Comment: Community Builer might be your best choice if you want to make full use of custom fields. It also integrates with other components such as Kunena which can be an advantage. Update you Joomla version to 2.5.7 whilst you're at it ;)

Answer (score 7):

the problem is how to access to this profile data. 
this

```
JFactory::getUser()->get('address1','');
```

doesn't seem to work.

but this does the job:

```
jimport('joomla.user.helper');
$user = & JFactory::getUser();
$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->id);
echo $profile->profile['address1'];
```

Comment: +1. but please change `$user = & JFactory::getUser();` to `$user =  JFactory::getUser();` to avoid strict warnings.

Answer (score 2):

In joomla 2.5 You can add extra 12 fields to the user registration. The step for adding the extra field is  Go to the Plug-In Manager (Extensions > Plug-In Manager) and look for a plugin named as User - Profile. This plugin comes with Joomla by default, so you don't need to install anything. However, plugin is disabled by default, so you must enable it first. This single click is enough to change Joomla registration form dramatically and add 12 useful fields:

Answer (score 2):

Joomla 2.5.x has User - Profile plugin with 12 fields, if you need further fields try this:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/14303

Answer (score 1):

there is two relative fields in joomla 2.5.1 register page.
for view section:

```
Joomla_2.5.1/components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php
```

which will possible get data from its relevant file that is:

```
Joomla_2.5.1/components/com_users/controllers/registration.php
Joomla_2.5.1/components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml
Joomla_2.5.1/components/com_users/models/registration.php
```

try to modify these files

Comment: Sorry, as i'm very new to PHP programming, would you mind guiding me along? I'm not very sure how to edit those files.

Comment: I only know the first step is to edit the registration.xml file and add in the fields that i need. What should i do after that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the extension [**Community Builder**](http://www.joomlapolis.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=12&Itemid=2). It is one of the most popular Joomla! extensions, and it has a lot of capabilities. Allowing you as site administrator to define extra fields for the user profile is just the start of it.

CB, as it is called, has a plugin architecture. Both the CB developers and others have developed plugins that let you extend what CB can do for you. Connections to Facebook and Twitter, paid subscriptions, rating other users — there are many possibilities.

CB is free software, GPL licensed. However, you pay for access to the documentation and for support. Also, some of the plugins are proprietary software.

**Update**: The current version of CB is 1.7.1, and it supports Joomla! 1.0 through 1.7, but not Joomla 2.5.x. However, as of February 7, 2012, [**Community Builder 1.8 is in RC**](http://www.joomlapolis.com/news/18251-community-builder-18-rc-released). It supports and has been tested with all Joomla! versions through 2.5.1.  RC stands for "Release Candidate", so it's not yet ready to use on production sites — though the developers say it powers their own [joomlapolis.com](http://www.joomlapolis.com/) site. "The goal is to release CB 1.8 stable version before Joomla 1.7 end of life date", developers say.

Comment: Thanks. I have visited the link you gave and found out that its for Joomla™ (1.7, 1.6, 1.5 and 1.0). It didn't include Joomla 2.5.1

Comment: @Lloydworth, see the update, CB 1.8 has a Release Candidate version which does support Joomla 2.5.x.

Comment: @Lloydworth, that's correct. The business model for Community Builder is that certified versions of the software are freely available, but pre-release versions, support, and documentation cost money. BTW your question asked "how can this be done", not "how can this be done for zero money".