# Changes in source of components of Joomla is not reflecting

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am modifying the source of Joomla components  .Sometimes the changes are not reflecting but sometimes it works.

Is there any clean or repair and rebuild method in joomla ?

So i can get the effect of my modification immediately.

Comment: what exactly are you changing and in which file?

Comment: I am changing in the Componets->com_users->controllers->user.php . I am trying to customize the log-in method . Sometime it works but sometime is not.

Comment: welcome to Stack overflow. A question like this should be accompanied by code example and exact description of the problem. Otherwise you will be getting nothing!

Comment: In joomla, this Componets->com_users->controllers->user.php file have this code

`class UsersControllerUser extends UsersController
{
 public function login()
 {
  die('testing'); 
  
  JSession::checkToken('post') or jexit(JText::_('JInvalid_Token'));

  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  .
  ..
  ...
 }
}`

The die in the above code is not working always, but sometimes, it works.

Once I commented the whole code even removed the file, but my site is still running properly.

Comment: Thank you @AhmadAlfy . is it fine now ???

Comment: You should never try to edit core Joomla files. Not even very experienced users do this as future updates may override the, it cause cause problems with the code, and may pose security issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Abdul what you want to achieve by modifying Joomla's source files. You can do it by writing plugin without hacking the core files. There are many users events available in Joomla. I think you want to do something on login so you can use onUserLogin event.
Check this link. http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User

Comment: Thank you @atpatil11. I am trying to implement custom logic after logic. Your answer seems good. i am looking for the place to insert code. Kindly see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9206168/2571183) problem also.